# Is the Verizon iPhone 5 (unlocked) compatible with Rogers?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, lte

Would I get LTE from a Verizon iPhone 5 on Rogers?

According to [Apple's LTE page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/) I won't be getting LTE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct, Verizon's iPhone 5 won't work on the Rogers LTE network.

According to Rogers' [iPhone 5 page](http://www.rogers.com/web/link/wirelessBuyFlow?forwardTo=PhoneThenPlan&productType=normal&productId_Detailed=IP516WHT&N=52%2011%204294925041), the specs include:

> LTE Bands:700/1700

In the Apple iPhone 5 page you've quoted, you need to get model **A1428** which supports LTE Band 17 (700 MHz). Rogers is explicitly listed there as one of the supported LTE networks. If you want to get an unlocked Verizon iPhone 5 (model **A1429 CDMA**), you won't be able to use LTE on the Rogers network. You'd be better off getting the unlocked AT&T version.

Answer (score 1):

No, the LTE bands used by Rogers are different than those supported by the Verizon iPhone 5. You will be able to get 3G and voice access, but not LTE.